# How do I zero-fill a number?

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal, converters

I have a working decimal to binary converter, but I want it to ALWAYS show 8 digits,
so if I put in 3 it will say '00000011' and not '11'
Anyone a clue how this can be done?
my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ConvertToBinary(dec) {
            var bits = [];
            var dividend = dec;
            var remainder = 0;
            while (dividend >= 2) {
                remainder = dividend % 2;
                bits.push(remainder);
                dividend = (dividend - remainder) / 2;
            }
            bits.push(dividend);
            bits.reverse();
            return bits.join("");


        }
```

```
<input type="text" id="txtDec" maxlength="3"/>
<input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="document.getElementById('spBin').innerHTML=ConvertToBinary(document.getElementById('txtDec').value);" />
<span id="spBin"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript already makes the conversion for you, from a number, using [toString](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString.html) method, because you can specify the *radix* (see the link above):

```
var n = 13;
console.log(n.toString(2)) // "1101"
```

If you want add lead zero, in case less then 8, you could have:

```
var bits = n.toString(2);

console.log("00000000".substr(bits.length) + bits);
```

With just one method call.

**Edit:** this answer was written in 2013, nowadays the method [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) can be used instead for the padding:

```js
console.log(n.toString(2).padStart(8, "0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
return String('000000000' + bits.join("")).slice(-8);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VRfVn/) (change "dividend" to try with different numbers)

Basically adds 8 zeros to the left and then removes anything more than 8 characters long from the left.

Answer (score 0):

How about before `bits.reverse();`  You do a while loop like this:

```
while(bits.length < 8){
    bits.push(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example solution that will left-pad a number with zeros

@param "num" the number to be left-padded with zeros

@param "width" the number of characters required as a result

@return String the left-padded number

```
function zeroFill(num, width) {
str = String((new Array(width+1)).join('0') + num).slice(-width)
return str
}
```

There are other solutions which use a loop to create the zeros.